# Producing message to apache kafka from python application in k8s container is succeeded, but could not consume message

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I clone docker elk repository;

> https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk

```
$ docker exec -it broker /bin/bash
## create topic
$ kafka-topics --bootstrap-server broker:9092 --create --topic events --partitions 3 replication-factor 1
## confirm created
$ kafka-topics --bootstrap-server broker:9092 --describe --topic events
## bootstrap consumer
$ kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server broker:29092 --topic events --group G1 --from-beginning

## in another pane
$ docker exec -it broker /bin/bash
$ kafka-console-producer --broker-list broker:29092 --topic events
> test
→ could confirm "test" in consumer pane
```

But I cannot confirm that consumer in pane consume messages from application in kubenetes container.

```
import kafka (== 2.0.2)

producer = kafka.KafkaProducer(
   bootstrap_servers="host.minikube.internal:9092",
   api_version=(0, 10, 2)
)

resp = producer.send("events", key=b'message-key', value=b'message-value')
print(resp) ## output → <kafka.producer.future.FutureRecordMetadata object at 0xffffb54106d0>
producer.flush() ## in develop environment
```

docker compose advertised listener

```
KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
```

I expect that apache kafka consume messages from application in k8s container.

Comment: you have a setup on docker-compose, what this has to do with the k8s setup?, in the python script, you use `host.minikube.internal:9092` and in the consumer you listen to `broker:29092`, do you have 2 kafka brokers?

Comment: > you have a setup on docker-compose, what this has to do with the k8s setup?
I needed to add sending streaming events to apache kafka to existed application in k8s.
i think kafka listened to localhost:9092, so my bootstrap servers is host.minikube.internal:9092, is it wrong?

Comment: And this command(kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server broker:29092~) is executed in broker docker container.

Comment: kafka instance you ran on docker-compose can't be seen out of the box to k8s, each live in a different network setup, you either install kafka on k8s so that the application and kafka live in the same network to be able to communicate with, or make dockerize your script and make it part of the docker-compose file